# Prove or disprove that any solution of ODE is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me to solve the following problem:

Differential equation $y''+y=f(x)$ has the solution $g(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)$ is bounded.

Is it true that any solution of this equation is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$?

Unfortunately I have no ideas how to handle this question.
I do not need full solution for this problem, just the answer and hint why the answer is true or what should I notice and know to provide the answer myself.

Thanks a lot for any hints and answers!

Comment: Are the $f$ at the r.h.s. and the solution $f$ the same function?

Comment: No, sorry, just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear non-homogeneous second order equation. 
Since $u_1(x) = \cos x$ and $u_2(x) = \sin x$ are independent solutions of the linear equation $y'' + y = 0$,
the solutions of your equation are of the form
$$
y(x) = c_1 \sin x + c_2\cos x + g(x),
\qquad c_1, c_2\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Now it is easy to conclude.

Comment: So any other solution is different from this bounded solution by a solution of homogeneous equation which is bounded, so it must be bounded too, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok, sweet. I've just posted last ODE question for today, can you please check it as well?